# How do I instantiate a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently trying to run this solution but I am  having trouble understanding what is actually going on here. The error I get back is:

```
line 39, in <module>
    map_manufacturer_model()
TypeError: map_manufacturer_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

By reading documents online it means i need to instantiate a object before calling it? But I'm still unsure what that means. I have my data frame and I'm trying to loop over everything inside to get the correct manufactures and meter models? Any guidance on this issue would be much apricated!

Test csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nxLO7c2veCJOHp7Uw_3ZuUtYUvvMHtelEE-UW9QpY9g/edit#gid=0

```
gas_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\test.csv')

manufacturers = {'G4F0': 'FLN', 'G4K0': 'HWL', 'E6S1': 'LPG'}

meter_models = {'G4F0': {'1': 'G4SZV-1', '2': 'G4SZV-2'},
                'G4K0': {'': 'BK-G4E'},
                'E6S1': {'': 'G470'},
                }

def map_manufacturer_model(s):
    s = str(s)
    model = 'unknown'
    try:
        manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
        for k, m in meter_models[s[:4]].items():
            if s[-4:].startswith(k):
                model = m
                break
    except KeyError:
        manufacturer = 'unknown'

    return pd.Series({'New Meter Manufacturer': manufacturer,
                      'New Meter Model': model
                      })


gas_data[['New Meter Manufacturer', 'New Meter Model']] = gas_data['New Serial Number'].apply(
    map_manufacturer_model)


map_manufacturer_model()
```

Comment: Issue is with the last line, why are you calling method again?

Comment: **By reading documents online it means i need to instantiate a object before calling it?** Only if you're calling a class method, not an ordinary function.

Comment: in addition to what @Barmar said, your function takes a string argument that you are not passing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with instantiating an object. So clearly you misunderstood how the solution works here.

You pass a **function** object (not **class name**) called `map_manufacturer_model` as parameter to `.apply(..)` so the latter can call `map_manufacturer_model` within the library's function implementation. So you shouldn't be the one to call `map_manufacturer_model`.

So remove the last line.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is becuase i was calling back the function again even though it already being called back in the apply(map_manufacturer_model)